# HTML Music Player - Absolute file location (i.e. C:\song.mp3)

Tags: javascript, php, html

Good morning,

I have put together a music player using modified examples on SO. My player plays songs fine if the file is located within the website's directory, however I wish to change it so that the source can exist anywhere on the server.  I have looked on here for examples of this however the ones I find either don't work or do not apply to my situation.

Currently I have this line:

```
<audio id="audio-player" src="media/song.mp3" type="audio/mp3" controls="controls"></audio>
```

which plays the file located within the folder media in the website directory.

What I want is something like this:

```
<audio id="audio-player" src="C:\song.mp3" type="audio/mp3" controls="controls"></audio>
```

Currently I am doing it with HTML and JS but am open to any suggestions. All I really care about is that I can make a music player that can play files from any location, regardless of how this is done.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the url is `C:\song.mp3` you tell the user to access THEIR local C drive. you need to create a proxy webpage that accesses files that are not in your local web root (public_html). So you can create a webpage in your local webroot that has the following code :

proxy.php

```
<?php 
    header("Content-Type: audio/mp3");
    echo file_get_contents("C:\\audio\\" . $_GET["name"] . ".mp3"); 
?>
```

If you wanted to access the desired audio file you would go to the url `proxy.php?name=song`. Like so

```
<audio id="audio-player" src="proxy.php?name=song" type="audio/mp3" controls="controls"></audio>
```

You should also prevent any `"..\"` and possibly `"~"` so they cant access parent folders.

Comment: I think I understand from this. So basically this will create a URL referencing the file. So for my music player, I would want to run proxy.php to create the url, then src = proxy.php?name=song ?

Comment: Yes, the source should point to your proxy page. This page finds a file in your local server's audio folder and echos the bytes of that file. Which is treated as mp3 audio file. (PHP can generate ANY kind of file not just HTML in this instance it generates an mp3 file)

Comment: As a matter of fact you should be able to type `http://yoursite.com/proxy.php?name=song` into your url and it should play the audio file in the browser (if mp3 is supported).

Comment: hm.. I am still not doing something right apparently. I have changed the line to be [audio id="audio-player" src="proxy.php?name=song" type="audio/mp3" controls="controls"></audio>] and have the proxy.php just as you have listed with song.mp3 in C:\audio\.  Visiting localhost/proxy.php?name=song results in the song being displayed in text in my browser which means at least it is being directed to the file even if not played.

Comment: Oops, I used the `header` function improperly, please look at the code edit.

Answer (score 1):

Browsers cannot access arbitrary files on the server's file system. You can't give a Windows file path on the server.

You need to:

- Make the file available over HTTP
- Give the URL to that file

Comment: I am sorry but how would I go about making it available over HTTP? Could I do something like this? src="file///C:song.mp3"

Comment: The same way as you make everything else available on your server. You put it somewhere under the directory you have configured as your DocumentRoot.